# Suppress Windows7 messages in Session 0

Tags: windows-7, wix, windows-installer

We have a windows service that gets installed and runs on users system in the background, but on some windows machine user get an error "A device or program has requested your attention" This is specific to Windows 7.

This is because when we are installing the .exe on the user machine using MSI(created with WIX), the installer job I believe runs on Session 0, and when any prompt appears the user is prompted that a program has requested attention and he gets switched to Session 0. Can we suppress messages for installer or exe running in Session 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this you will have to determine what UI is shown if the user switches to Session 0, what shows it, and how to remove it.

Services run on Session 0. Before Windows Vista, they could interact with the desktop, so many did. Chances are your service is trying to show some UI. Upon detecting this, Windows is trying to help you out. Fix the service to avoid showing UI, and the message will go away.

It's plausible that this could also occur for a deferred custom action in the system context (as those are invoked by the Windows Installer service), but I've never run into this scenario. If so, the fix is the same: make that action not show any UI.

Comment: We are trying to make all our executable run without the console. Our exes are built in GO, some of them run during the install process and display a console window for less than a second, the user may not even notice this. This works on all other Windows platforms but fails on Windows 7, so we are trying to use the "go build -ldflags -Hwindowsgui filename.go" option so that our exes does not attach a console to itself

Comment: Hm. I didn't think that being a console app caused problems here, but it's been a while since I tested on Windows 7. And I've never tested a service written in go. Perhaps add some of that to your question so people with relevant experience are more likely to chime in. (In the meantime, ensure you've got the right culprit by skipping the service install to see if the symptoms disappear.)

Comment: Hey an update, detaching the .exe from the console  seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Michael's correct, but I want to expand on it a little.

The issue isn't primarily about session 0 or services. It is about *anything* that tries to show a UI that is not part of the interactive user's current session. The main problem is the shatter attack where (for example) something running with the system (or otherwise privileged) account shows UI to the (perhaps limited) interactive user. The window into the privileged process is a security hole. As a result, attempts by an install to run custom actions with the system account (deferred CAs) that show UI are an issue, as are services. Session 0 is really just part of the implementation that is intended to address the security issues.

So yes, address UI attempts from your services and from (primarily deferred) custom actions in the install.