# How to Screen Capture using java as windows service?

Tags: java, swing

I am running my java application as windows service and using `java.awt.Robot` class to capture screen, but I getting a black screen.

### Code:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(1400, 900);
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage bufferImg = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
ImageIO.write(bufferImg, JPG_FORMAT, saveLocation);
```

Comment: Make sure you that when you go to the properties of the service (in `services.msc`), you have selected "connect interactively with the desktop" (or something like that) on the second tab

Comment: @Ferrybig  I am using tanuki wrapper to run my java as service `wrapper.ntservice.interactive=true` and I checked, that allow service to interact with the desktop, still getting a black screen.

Comment: According to the link in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891819/windows-service-screen-capture-returns-black-screen it seems like services are no longer allowed to interact with the user data, and ticking that box makes a virtual session for the service, instead of connecting to the session of the user. You could split up your service into a user program, and a backend service, so it can do its screen capture

Comment: Thank you @Ferrybig, also referred [Session 0 isolation ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092870/suppress-windows7-messages-in-session-0) and my question is can take screen capture of all the session like 0,1..etc?

Comment: Any possibilities to overcome issue other than user program